# how do I use CommaSeparatedIntegerField in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

There is almost no documentation for it here:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield

Maybe someone could, by example, show me how to populate a `CommaSeparatedIntegerField` in Django?

-thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Looking at the source for django...

```
class CommaSeparatedIntegerField(CharField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'form_class': forms.RegexField,
            'regex': '^[\d,]+$',
            'max_length': self.max_length,
            'error_messages': {
                'invalid': _(u'Enter only digits separated by commas.'),
            }
        }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(CommaSeparatedIntegerField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Check out that regex validator.  Looks like as long as you give it a list of integers and commas, django won't complain.

You can define it just like a charfield basically:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    int_list = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=200)
```

And populate it like this:

```
f = Foo(int_list="1,2,3,4,5")
```

Comment: Do you know if the max_length corresponding to the field includes commas?

Answer (score 18):

I would like to add that this Field [is depricated in Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield). In Django 1.9+ a `CharField` with `validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list]` should be used.

Answer (score 15):

> Works for versions greater than Django 1.9

**First Step:-**   *Import this* ( May change in newer versions , so double check that)

```
from django.core.validators import validate_comma_separated_integer_list
```

**Second Step :-** *Write Field*

```
class RestaurantLocation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=False)
    choices_field = models.CharField(validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list],max_length=200, blank=True, null=True,default='')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Note:** Please make sure to use `default = ''` if you are adding column to an already created database otherwise you would get the following option to choose after running `python manage.py migrate`

---

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'choices_field' to restaurantlocation without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a 
null value for this column)
2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: For the use in views.py : 

example_string="1,2,3,4,5"
Use [int(s) for s in example_string.split(',')]

Answer (score 7):

I just happened to have dealt with CommaSeparatedIntegerField in my latest project. I was using MySQL and it seemed like supplying a string of comma separated integer values is very DB friendly e.g. '1,2,3,4,5'. If you want to leave it blank, just pass an empty string.

It does act like a CharField, and beaved in a weird way for me.. I ended up with values like "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" including the brackets in my database! So watch out!